# UWP Listview in Gridview not increasing

Tags: xaml, listview, gridview, uwp

I've got a GridView to display some data. Each of the GridView items is a ListView which is increasing during runtime.
I'd like the GridView to increase as well - but it is only showing a scrollbar inside the GridView item.
One further requirement would be that each GridView Item should be aligned on top of the item.

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Width="1080">
<GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>                     
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListData}" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="&#x1f382;" 
                                FontSize="20" 
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Margin="0,0,10,10"
                                FontFamily="Sergoe UI"
                                Style="{StaticResource BasicTextBlock}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding NameString, Converter={StaticResource DataBindingDebugConverter}}" 
                                Grid.Column="2"
                                Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                FontSize="16"
                                Style="{StaticResource BasicTextBlock}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView> 
    </DataTemplate>
</GridView.ItemTemplate>
<GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,20,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="360" />
    </Style>
</GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
</GridView>
```

Comment: Do not do it. It's a bad idea to have `ListView`s inside a `GridView`. Use an `ItemsControl` instead.

Comment: @JustinXL ItemsControl was the hint to get it done. Thanks! 
What I just found out is that ListBox and ListView take up all the space available to them from the parent and no more. And this was my issue.

Comment: Yeah and also keep in mind ListView is a complex and heavy control. You normally just use one on your page. :)

Comment: I went further in this topic and it was not working again today. But I also found out the reason: The GridView item height is based on the first item like it is described here: [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a931f6f8-b0c5-4eb8-adae-c7a81635f88e/uwpxaml-gridview-item-heights-based-on-the-first-item-only-can-we-change-it-to-take-item?forum=wpdevelop) 
so the problem is not really the ListView, it's the Gridview itself. 
I need to set the height of the gridView based on the biggest item in a row. any ideas?
I will make a new Question for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the correct answer for this question is (based on the hint of JustinXL)

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Width="1080">
<GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListData, Converter={StaticResource DataBindingDebugConverter}}" x:Name="BirthdayListView" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,20,0,0">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="&#x1f382;" 
                                    FontSize="16" 
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    Margin="0,0,10,10"
                                    FontFamily="Sergoe UI"
                                    Style="{StaticResource BasicTextBlock}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding NameString, Converter={StaticResource DataBindingDebugConverter}}" 
                                    Grid.Column="2"
                                    Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                    FontSize="16"
                                    Style="{StaticResource BasicTextBlock}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridView.ItemTemplate>
<GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,20,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="360" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
    </Style>
</GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
</GridView>
```