# UWP GridView ItemHeight based on the biggest item in a row

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, uwp

As discussed already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41988345/uwp-listview-in-gridview-not-increasing) I've a problem with showing content in a `GridView`. Based on this [article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a931f6f8-b0c5-4eb8-adae-c7a81635f88e/uwpxaml-gridview-item-heights-based-on-the-first-item-only-can-we-change-it-to-take-item?forum=wpdevelop) I found out that `GridView` set the `Height` property for the items to the height of the first item. The problem for me is that I'd like to have the `Height` adjusted apdaptive based on the height of the content. 
So if the second item in a row is the biggest, all items in this row should get the size of the second item.

I've used this code for showing the GridView:

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Width="1080">
<GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListData, Converter={StaticResource DataBindingDebugConverter}}" x:Name="BirthdayListView" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,20,0,0">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="&#x1f382;" 
                                    FontSize="16" 
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    Margin="0,0,10,10"
                                    FontFamily="Sergoe UI"
                                    Style="{StaticResource BasicTextBlock}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding NameString, Converter={StaticResource DataBindingDebugConverter}}" 
                                    Grid.Column="2"
                                    Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                    FontSize="16"
                                    Style="{StaticResource BasicTextBlock}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridView.ItemTemplate>
<GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,20,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="360" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
    </Style>
</GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
</GridView>
```

**EDIT:**

If the calendar entries are on the first entry (Sonntag) everything is fine.
[image]

If the calendar entries are on the second item (Montag) they are hidden and the ItemHeight is not increasing.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

> Based on this article I found out that GridView set the Height property for the items to the height of the first item.

As you known the row height of `GridView` depend on the first item not the highest item. So we may need to [custom a panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/custom-panels-overview) for the `GridView`'s [`ItemPanel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx). For example, since the `Width` of your `GridView` is fixed value, we can create a `CustomPanel` as follows:

```
public class CustomPanel : Panel
{
    private double _maxWidth;
    private double _maxHeight;

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        var x = 0.0;
        var y = 0.0;
        foreach (var child in Children)
        { 
            if ((_maxWidth + x) > finalSize.Width)
            {
                x = 0;
                y += _maxHeight;
            }
            var newpos = new Rect(x, y, _maxWidth, _maxHeight);
            child.Arrange(newpos);
            x += _maxWidth;
        }
        return finalSize;
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    { 
        foreach (var child in Children)
        {
            child.Measure(availableSize);

            var desirtedwidth = child.DesiredSize.Width;
            if (desirtedwidth > _maxWidth)
                _maxWidth = desirtedwidth;

            var desiredheight = child.DesiredSize.Height;
            if (desiredheight > _maxHeight)
                _maxHeight = desiredheight;
        }            
        var itemperrow = Math.Floor(availableSize.Width / _maxWidth);
        var rows = Math.Ceiling(Children.Count / itemperrow);
        return new Size(itemperrow * _maxWidth,_maxHeight * rows );
    }
}
```

Then replace the `ItemsPanelTemplate` of `GridView` with the `CustomPanel`in XAML as follows:

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding}"   Width="1080" >
    <GridView.ItemTemplate> 
     ...  
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
       ... 
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <local:CustomPanel />                  
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
</GridView>
```